# Согласно Положения или с маленькой буквы положения

Tags: орфография

согласно Положения или с маленькой буквы положения

Comment: Обычно практикующие юристы прописывают сперва пункты или части статьи, а потом название документа, например: согласно п.2.2 Положения "О плановом контроле".

Answer (score 5):

Во-первых, согласно чему? ПоложениЮ.

Во-вторых, если имеется в виду определённое положение, то это имя собственное, правда, название пишется полностью, но если это канцелярско-деловой стиль и название упоминается несколько раз, то полностью пишется первый раз, а повторно — сокращённо Положение, но имеется в виду именно оно, вышеназванное, поэтому и с большой буквы. Например "Между тем в Положении о государственных наградах Российской Федерации от 2 марта 1994 г. установлено... Согласно Положению, награды наследуются..."

А вот если бы речь шла о любом положении, было бы со строчной буквы (с маленькой).

Answer (score 0):

Следует отметить, что нередко в договорах, законодательных актах, официальных заявлениях и так далее пишется полное название с большой буквы, а потом в скобках указывается "далее Положение", например: "Между тем в Положении о государственных наградах Российской Федерации от 2 марта 1994 г. (далее Положение) установлено, что <...>". Это, конечно, невозможно, если говорится про несколько положений.